# Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted

Tags: php, mysql

I am using 000webhost.com and I am using phpMyAdmin there. I am getting this error from MySQL when I run my PHP script as the title says:

> Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16.
>
> The table is probably corrupted.

Is there any solution for this?

```
<?php
$username="usrname";
$password="passwd";
$database="a1xxxxx_mydb";
$host="mysqlxx.000webhost.com";
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
if (isset($_GET["userLatitude"]) && isset($_GET["userLongitude"])) {

 $userLatitude=$_GET['userLatitude']; 
 $userLongitude=$_GET['userLongitude']; 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT locationName, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(floatval(     $userLatitude) )) * cos( radians( locationLatitude ) ) * cos( radians( locationLongitude ) - radians( floatval($userLatitude)) ) + sin( radians(floatval($userLongitude)) ) * sin( radians( locationLatitude) ) ) ) AS distance 
         FROM Location HAVING distance < 2 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 ,20") or die(mysql_error()); 
echo $result;

 // check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   // looping through all results
   // products node
  $response["Location"] = array();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["locationName"] = $row["locationName"];
    $product["locationInfo"] = $row["locationInfo"];
    $product["locationLatitude"] = $row["locationLatitude"];
    $product["locationLongitude"] = $row["locationLongitude"];
    $product["locationPic"] = $row["locationPic"];
    $product["city"] = $row["city"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["Location"], $product);
 }
 // success
 $response["success"] = 1;

   // echoing JSON response
   echo json_encode($response);
 } else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
 }
 }
  else {
    // required field is missing
   $response["success"] = 0;
   $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

  // echoing JSON response
  echo json_encode($response);
 }
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: providing some more details would be a good start. Are you running a stored procedure? UDF? How about showing some of the code you're trying to run? We're good, but we're not psychic and cannot read your mind or remotely view your screen.

Comment: oh you are right , i am putting the code as fast as possible .I just can't connect to the 000webhost.com.I will post it.  Thank you :)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/956/resolving-issue-with-mysql-proc-after-upgrading-mysql-from-5-0-to-5-1

Comment: I am using the phpMyAdmin which the website provides me with ...

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Let your hoster run the `mysql_upgrade` script provided with his mysql-version, possibly force it.

Answer (score 132):

I had this error as well.  I fixed it by running

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Also, restart the mysql service by running

```
service mysqld restart
```

Comment: You might need the --force flag.

Comment: Just a small note. I had to run with sudo, ie `sudo mysql_upgrade -uxxx -pxxx`. otherwise we have this error: `Could not create the upgrade info file '/var/lib/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info' in the MariaDB Servers datadir, errno: 13`

Comment: In case you are using latest versions of mariadb.... the comand is the same but using maria... `maria-upgrade -u root -p`

Comment: 100th upvote ;) because this worked for me too, Just one extra step I needed is I have to repair ```global_priv``` table of mysql database, then it allowed me to upgrade mysql.

Comment: This also worked for me when moving from MySQL 5.2 to MariaDB 10.3 after I imported data backed up from MySQL into MariaDB.

Comment: worked for me but with: mariadb-upgrade -u root -p

Comment: After running mysql_upgrade command, it solved the subject error. But it created another problem like I can not connect to mysql using root@localhost or pma@localhost. phpMyAdmin not working!! Finally, I have to use 'skip-grant-tables' in the my.ini file of mysql config.

Answer (score 42):

I had the same problem when I updated XAMPP from xampp-osx-7.2.10 to 7.3.9 in MacOS Mohave. So the solution was:

Find the file mysql_upgrade in "Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Applications⁩ ▸ ⁨XAMPP⁩ ▸ ⁨xamppfiles⁩ ▸ ⁨bin⁩" and double click on it.

Comment: i tried to run it by double clicking, but i get "cannot execute binary file"..

Comment: It works for me. Restart mysql after double click

Comment: run from command says mysql_upgrade deprecated. Double-clicking on the binary works perfectly.

Comment: same in Linux, it works

Answer (score 27):

A similar error appeared in MySQL Workbench 8.0.21 after installing XAMPP 7.4.8 on Ubuntu 18.04. There were no problems using phpMyAdmin.

```
Error Code: 1558 Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100413. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error
```

Solution:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade
```

Problem solved

**Credits**: There appear to be a bug in XAMPP - https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=78386&sid=3d3824dd0b6aa2e33c3adc73c744b4b4

Comment: `sudo` /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade - sudo was required for me

Comment: `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade`

Answer (score 22):

This error happens when a bad upgrade is done. For example, it happens if you upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1 but don't run the mysql_upgrade script; or, in rare cases, it probably happens if you directly upgrade from 5.0 to 5.5. (Many people does this, but such updrages are not officially supported)
You say you are using a hosting service - well, I think that you should create a ticket and tell them about the problem. If you don't have the SUPER privilege, there is nothing you can do.
But if you have that right, simply run mysql_upgrade:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-upgrade.html

Comment: Running `mysql_upgrade -u root -p` fixed my database for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when I updated the mysql server from 5.5 to 5.7 in Debian 8  (jessie). In my case, it worked fine when I executed the follow command:

```
mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p
```

Comment: how to run this in localhost ?

Comment: What to do if the mysql service cannot start, because of the error?

Answer (score 6):

I am using xampp on Ubuntu 20.04 and the my problem that return this same message error was solved with this solution:

1. Go to the xampp directory: cd /opt/lampp/
2. Go to the bin directory: cd bin
3. Execute the script: sudo ./mysql_upgrade

Credits: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171409/how-to-run-mysql-upgrade-when-using-xampp

Answer (score 2):

Although you may be correct about the necessity for upgrade, that's not the only reason this error occurs.

When the following is called with a query that returns 1 row

```
 my $rv = $sth_indexq->fetchall_arrayref;
```

the following error is reported:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. Created with MySQL 50520, now running 50528. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error. at 
...
```

However, the real cause of the error was use of fetchall_arrayref instead of fetchrow_arrayref.  The following worked without errors:

```
my $rv = $sth_indexq->fetchrow_arrayref;
```

The data in **$rv** was only **1 level deep, not 2**.

The mysql_upgrade solution may very well solve this issue, but the simple solution is know your data and use the right retrieval code.

J.White

Comment: always format with code, using ctrl+k if you have wrote some code.

Comment: "know your data": true, but mysql.proc is not our data (and it took me hours, too many, to notice that...)

Answer (score 1):

I was using a windows 10 system and the solution that worked for me was
mysql_upgrade -u root -p

But you need to ensure that the path to the mysql_upgrade script which is present in the mysql/bin folder of your installation directory needs to be added in the environment variable path for this command to work

Answer (score 1):

Hit on browser below command

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade
```

Comment: you mean on terminal*

Answer (score 1):

### **For Linux**

If you are using LAMPP, then you can fix it like -

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade
```

else if you installed mysql separately, then you can like this -

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p 
service mysqld restart
```

For any other OS, you can simply go to **bin** directory of lampp installation & try to find mysql_upgrade file & execute it.

Answer (score 1):

## If use XAMPP on macOS M1

[XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

my case (in this case I'm using prisma in nextjs) if it happens Hopefully it will help in other cases more or less.

> Error: Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100428. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error
>
> 0: sql_schema_connector::flavour::mysql::connection::describe_schema at schema-engine/connectors/sql-schema-connector/src/flavour/mysql/connection.rs:34
>
> 1: schema_core::state::DevDiagnostic at schema-engine/core/src/state.rs:270

Find ‘mysql_upgrade’
In my case `mysql_upgrade` is in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin

open your terminal and run

1. `cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin`
2. `mysql_upgrade` or `mysql_upgrade -u root -p`

If error
`zsh: command not found: mariadb-upgrade` problem is can't find mariadb-upgrade

> `vi ~/.zshrc`

Add

```
. . .
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/ (is mysql_upgrade directory)
```

Example my case

```
. . .
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

save and run
`source ~/.zshrc`

3. run `mysql_upgrade -u root -p`

If error
my case
change cmd

> `mysql_upgrade -u root -p` to
> `mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force --force`

i'm sorry if used the wrong word.

Thank you

Comment: This comment was helpful for me but i needed to run the following 'sudo ./mysql_upgrade -u root'

Comment: Thank you. it's answer number 3 ? @vdidxho

Answer (score 0):

This my happen when eg. upgrading instead of migrating;

The part where it reads `version check failed` is the relevant part:

```
Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Obviously this is about an incompatible client version, but the `mysql` database is also different.

This here would be the current definition of the [`mysql.proc`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlproc-table/) table ... which shows that enum column `type` has changed and that column  `aggregate` has been added, since MariaDB 10.3.3.

Yet another problem is:

> In MariaDB 10.4 and later, this table uses the Aria storage engine.

Downgrading the server to 5.x and deleting the InnoDB log files, then restoring table `proc` helped; (for MariaDB 5.x): https://github.com/google/mysql/blob/master/scripts/mysql_system_tables.sql

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was caused by prefixing a table alias in front of `COUNT()` accidentally:

```
MariaDB> SELECT x.COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT 1) AS x;
ERROR 1558 (HY000): Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100137, now running 100334. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error

MariaDB> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT 1) AS x;
+-------------+
| COUNT(test) |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

As you see, without the prefix before `COUNT()` it works. I was adding the table alias to all SELECT fields and, thereby, accidentally also added before the `COUNT()`. Whether this would give a *different* error message on a fresh database, I don't know, but the server has been running fine for years and by fixing the query the error goes away so... it seems like a runtime/syntax error to me, not an upgrade/restart problem like for the others in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

can you use it for linux
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After reading so many sites finally found the soultion on https://iqcode.com/code/html/column-count-of-mysqlproc-is-wrong-expected-21-found-20-created-with-mariadb-100108-now-running-100419-please-use-mysql-upgrade-to-fix-this-error-xampp

These are the steps you need to follow(linux/xampp)

1. go to terminal and type /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p
2. after that enter the mysql user password if it worked well
   then type exit (if it doesn't have password hit enter without
   typing anything)
3. after that type cd /opt/lampp/bin and now type
   sudo ./mysql_upgrade -u root -p
   , enter your password and tadam , here is your mysql upgraded