# MySQL 5.7 Error 1457

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have just upgraded MySQL from version 5.0 to 5.7. When every time I execute `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` query, I got this error.

```
[Err] 1457 - Failed to load routine db.ClosePeriod. The table mysql.proc is missing, corrupt, or contains bad data (internal code -6)
```

I select the ClosePeriod procedure in mysql.proc, the data is exists. I try to repair it, that table is not corrupted or crash.

Any solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

You should run `mysql_upgrade` after you upgrade the MySQL software.

Sometimes new versions of the software depends on new tables being created in the system schema. The mysql_upgrade tool makes sure to create these new tables.

Since you skipped from 5.0 to 5.7, you jumped forward in time about 10 years' worth of software versions. :-) There were certainly changes to the system tables in that time.

For more information, please read:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html

Comment: I followed this reference when upgrade from 5.0 to 5.7. [link_mysql](http://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-directly-from-mysql-5-0-to-5-6-with-mysqldump/)

Comment: But I got this error or warning while upgrading. `mysql_upgrade: (non fatal) [ERROR] 1805: Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted.` Is it any connection with my problem or I miss doing something when upgrade?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177465/column-count-of-mysql-proc-is-wrong-expected-20-found-16-the-table-is-probabl