# ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 48. The table is probably corrupted

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with mysql as following:

```
mysql> SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
+------+
| User |
+------+
| root |
| root |
|      |
| root |
|      |
| root |
+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'dummy'@'localhost';
ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. 
Expected 45, found 48. The table is probably corrupted
```

Have anyone meet this problems?Thanks

Comment: Try `CREATE USER 'dummy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '[password]';`

Comment: mysql> CREATE USER 'dummy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'dummy';
ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 48. The table is probably corrupted   It's still not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177465/column-count-of-mysql-proc-is-wrong-expected-20-found-16-the-table-is-probabl)

Comment: It seems to be specific for 5.6->5.7 upgrade

Answer (score 15):

Use the following script:

```
alter table user drop column is_role;
alter table user drop column default_role;
alter table user drop column max_statement_time;
alter table user modify max_user_connections int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
flush privileges;
```

credit:
https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/mysql-and-percona-server/48583-column-count-of-mysql-user-is-wrong-expected-45-found-48

Comment: Your fix worked for me. I migrated from mysql to percona and that generated the mentioned error.

Answer (score 14):

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Then restart database.

see: https://nixcp.com/error-1805-hy000-column-count-of-mysql-user-is-wrong/

The blog write:

> ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Table is
> probably corrupted error can be fixed by running a simple
> mysql_upgrade command. mysql_upgrade tool is used often to check for
> mysql table incompatibilities (crashed or corrupted tables) running on
> the current MySQL version. It can also be used to upgrade mysql tables
> if needed. In this case, we will use it to fix any corrupted tables.

Comment: As the answer is not very explanatory, to explain what it does is that it redefines the mysql.user table, moves the existing users to an inactive state and copies the old users to the new correct format.

Comment: Also the link is broken, with a "Error establishing a database connection" - pretty funny given the context :-)

Comment: link is now fixed

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue occurred after I upgraded from PHP5 to PHP7. I needed to go into PHP.ini (xampp/php/php.ini) and uncomment the following line:

```
extension=mysqli
```

Restart xampp, and it was good to go!