# #1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. (XAMPP Mysql)

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am running my MySQL project and suddenly get the bellow ERROR

```
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `testTable`
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Table 'testDB.testTable' doesn't exist in engine
```

I tried to solve this very hard and after struggling the whole day I just decided to drop my database
and when I go to PHPMyAdmin and try to drop my database it throws the ERROR that

```
#1558 - Column count of MySQL.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100410. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error
```

I tried to find the solution of these and all I getting is to upgrade my MySQL server 
[SOLUTION WHICH I FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177465/column-count-of-mysql-proc-is-wrong-expected-20-found-16-the-table-is-probabl) but unfortunately it will not help me out because my MySQL server is running with XAMPP and i am still stuck at this any kind of help is appreciable.

thanks in advance

Comment: From https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_upgrade/ explains that "_`mysql_upgrade` is a tool that checks and updates your tables to the latest version._" It is not asking you to upgrade your MySQL/MariaDB server

Comment: It does not matter that your mysql was installed as part of XAMPP or standalone, the answer in that other question still applies.

Comment: I was trying to create a function when I faced the issue. Upgrading the mysql helped resolving the issue. I went to the installation directory and ran  ./mysql_upgrade --force
. for me the path where i found the mysql_upgrade file was /c/xampp/mysql/bin