# Create MySql Tables On Docker Startup

Tags: mysql, database, docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I would like to setup some MySql tables upon Docker startup, however it doesn't look like it works. Here's my `DockerfileMySql`:

```
FROM mysql

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE football_simulation

COPY initial.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

        mysql-development:
                image: mysql:5.7.30
                environment:
                        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
                        MYSQL_DATABASE: football_simulation
                ports:
                - "3308:3306"
                volumes:
                - ./initial.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

        admin:
                image: adminer
                ports:
                - "8080:8080"
```

Finally my `initial.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tournament
(    id     INTEGER      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I run `docker build .` and `docker-compose up` and go over to `localhost:8080`, the UI is up with `football_simulation` database setup, but with no tables inside. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Right above the create table statement, type `use football_simulation;` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @zedfoxus, just tried that and still doesn't work...

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36407682/2554537. Does that help?

Comment: It looks like it has helped a bit, I changed to MariaDB and used the entrypoint in the answer, but I get this error now: 

`Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 50730, now running 100413. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error` 

but still no sign of the tables. Wondering what went wrong...

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177465/. That should give you tips on fixing that.